# How do I get Jest to run tests against a rollup+babel build?

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, rollupjs, babel-jest

I'm trying to set up a React module with tests. I'm using rollup to compile everything, which works fine. But I'm trying to introduce testing as well.

My directory structure:

```
dist/
  |- index.js
src/
  |- .babelrc
  |- util.js
test/
  |- .babelrc
  |- util.test.js
rollup.config.js
```

So far, so good. I have a `.babelrc` in src that applies to my source files:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
}
```

and a separate one for the Jest tests, which doesn't have the exceptions Rollup requires:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "env", "react"]
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error when I run the tests, complaining about the very first es6 feature they run in to in the source file (`SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`). If I remove the module exception, then the test passes, but Rollup fails.

How do I get babel to apply the module exceptions for Rollup, but not for Jest? Or is there an entirely different way I should be configuring these?

Comment: I built a very simple rollup and jest boilerplate for you to use: https://github.com/algolia/rollup-jest-boilerplate

Answer (score 3):

I have managed a solution to this, but I don't like it and would love a more transparent one.

My `test/.babelrc` (with no module exceptions) is now at the root level of the project.

In my `rollup.config.js`, I have set `rollup-plugin-babel` to ignore the babelrc, and given it the options that were in my `src/.babelrc`:

```
babel({
  babelrc: false,
  presets: [
    ['es2015', { modules: false }],
    ['env', { modules: false }],
    'react',
  ],
  plugins: ['external-helpers'],
  exclude: 'node_modules/**',
}),
```

This seems to work, but having a `.babelrc` at the root level that isn't actually used in compiling the package seems like a recipe for confusion later down the line. Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently (although I wasn't using React), and having my .babelrc file in src/ produced the same error.

I use [this configuration](https://github.com/trainorpj/rollup-babel-jest-setup) for my projects now.  The README includes an explanation.

The key feature is that I've specified the babel config *in* the rollup.config.js, and I include the option `babelrc: false`.

I no longer get the error when I run my tests, and everything works perfectly.  Does this sound reasonable to you?

```
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      file: "build/index.cjs.js",
      format: "cjs"
    },
    {
      file: "build/index.es.js",
      format: "es"
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel({
      presets: [
        [
          "env",
          {
            modules: false
          }
        ]
      ],
      plugins: ["external-helpers"],
      babelrc: false
    })
  ]
};
```